# django path is not recognizing its intended view

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

code: urls.py

```
path('tools/<int:rate>/', ToolsView.as_view(), name="get-all-tools"),

path('tools/post/', ToolsView.as_view(), name="save-tool"),
```

code: views.py

```
class ToolsView(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, rate):
        objs = ToolsModel.objects.values_list()[:rate]
        if objs is None:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        data = []
        for obj in objs:
            print(obj)
            json = {}
            json['toolid'] = obj[0]
            json['tool_name'] = obj[1]
            json['tool_from'] = obj[2]
            json['tool_qty'] = obj[3]
            json['tool_state'] = obj[4]
            data.append(json)
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serialize = ToolsSerializer(data=data)
        if serialize.is_valid():
            serialize.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Whenever i call for `tools/post/` intended to call post method

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/tools/post/

i get

> get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rate'

but **rate** parameter is actually needed for `'tools/<int:rate>/'` which invokes my get method  ,example,

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/tools/5/

Needed help with these. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/tools/post/ into your browser, you will be performing a GET on the URL.  In your urls.py you map that route to `ToolsView.as_view()`.  This allows you to handle the different HTTP Methods via functions.  So `def post` will get called when a POST is requested.  But you are likely doing a GET, which will call the `def get(...)` method.  But because you aren't passing in a `rate` it's missing from the function arguments, hence the error.  To test the `post` method you need to perform a POST to http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/tools/post/.

Test Code:

```py
import requests

requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/help/tools/post/", data={})
```

Comment: can you give an example how can i make it work ? django rest framwork, should give me option to post data when post is requested.

Comment: By "make it work" do you mean performing a POST request?

Comment: Are you using the browser or curl/postman?
As saquintes states, if you're using the browser without the browsable API you'll just end up making a get-request, but if you specify that it's a post-request through either using curl or postman, or the browsable API, then surely your code should work.

Comment: @Thorvald  yes. i am using browser to test my api. Thanks, i got it what u said earlier in your answer. I should use postman to test my api.